# how to create custom pagination URL using thiswidget'zii.widgets.CListView' IN YII

Tags: php, yii

```
   $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Articles',array(
                        'criteria'=>array(
                            //'select' => 't.id, t.abc',
                            'order'=>'publish_on DESC',
                            'condition' => '',
                        ),
                        'pagination'=>array(
                            'pageSize'=>7,
                            'route' => 'site/index'

                        ),
                      ));
```

My url genarate like this : `xyz.com/site/index?Articles_page=2`

but i want : `xyz.com/?Articles_page=2`

Please help he how to do this ?

Comment: check this forum. May be helpful for your case: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9343-custom-urls-and-paging-problem/

Answer (score -2):

Hello Friend  finally i solved my problem. you have to  add `'/'=>'site/index'` this in your url rule in main.php file in config folder.